# How do I get Zygarde?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

So far in my playthrough I've heard there is a way to obtain Zygarde but I have never encountered a Zygarde in the wild nor has the game really showed me how to get Zygarde.

If there is a way to get the legendary Pokemon Zygarde, what is it, and how do I do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Zygarde has a rather unique method of being obtained in Sun/Moon. Rather than being encountered in the wild, you must collect [Zygarde Cells and Cores](http://pokemongohub.net/zygarde-cells-cores-locations-pokemon-sun-moon/) and use the [Reassembly Unit in route 16 when you have at least 10 cells.](http://serebii.net/pokedex-sm/718.shtml)